# How to Pre-populate Select option element with Selected atribute in JSP

Tags: jsp

I have a jsp page with a selection element named "category" with 4 options list with values smartphone, tablet,laptop and tv respectively. I am able to retrieve the stored category value from the database, my question is how do i pre-populate the list with the value retrieved in the database being the one selected in the option list in my jsp page. Here is what i have tried but not working:

```html
<select name ="categorieProduit" required>
                                    <option value ="cellulaire" <c:if test ="${theProduct.categorie == "cellulaire"}">selected</c:if>Cellulaire</option>
                                    <option value ="tablette" <c:if test ="${theProduct.categorie == "tablette"}">selected</c:if>>Tablette</option>
                                    <option value ="portable" <c:if test ="${theProduct.categorie == "portable"}">selected</c:if>>Ordinateur Portable</option>
                                    <option value ="tv" <c:if test ="${theProduct.categorie == "tv"}">selected</c:if>>Televiseur</option>
                                </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution :

```html
<select name ="categorieProduit">
  <option value ="cellulaire" ${theProduct.categorie == 'Cellulaire' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>Cellulaire</option>
  <option value ="tablette" ${theProduct.categorie == 'Tablette' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>Tablette</option>
  <option value ="portable" ${theProduct.categorie == 'Laptop' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>Ordinateur Portable</option>
  <option value ="televiseur" ${theProduct.categorie == 'Televiseur' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>Televiseur</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot.